# Piping Contents of Files from Filepaths to Single File - UNIX

Tags: file, unix, pipeline, cat, tee

I've got a list of filepaths, and would like to get the data from each of these files into a single communal file. The list of filepaths is in a file one-per-line, so I was hoping I could do something like:

```
cat listofpaths.txt >> combineddata.txt
```

Obviously that won't work since that's just going to get me the paths rather than the stuff within them - hmm...

I could do this using [Python](http://www.python.org/), but I'm assuming there a 1-liner to do it using a [UNIX](http://www.unix.org/) pipeline - anyone know what it'd be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
cat listofpaths.txt | xargs cat >> combineddata.txt
```

Comment: If it solved your problem you could 'accept' the answer.  :-)

Comment: Funky, done. I'm new to the industry, not quite got to grips with how this site works yet :) . Thanks again!